# Gap appears after removing section from Grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have 3 sections in my table, each section containing at most 1 row.

However, the center row, depending on a variable, may or may not be displayed in the tableview. My code implementation for this as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *currentUserId = [[UserStockInfo sharedUserStockInfo]getUserId];
    switch (section) {
        case 0: //Follow button
            return 1;
            break;

        case 1://Center cell
            if (self.user.exists) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
            break;

        case 2://question
            return 1;

        default:
            return 0;
            break;
        }

}
```

The issue I am facing is that for cases whereby the center cell is not supposed to be displayed, a gap still appears between the first and third sections (as seen below). How can I get rid of the excess gap after I remove the center cell?

**With center cell/section:**

[image]

**Without center cell/section (gap appears):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should set appropriate heights of footer and header of your `UITableView`.

Implement following methods in your delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

For example, for second section you could return 0:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if (section == 1) return 0;
     else return 10;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     if (section == 1) return 0;
     else return 10;
}
```

Hope, this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your advise. However, nothing changed after I added the methods above and after setting the footer and header heights to be 0.

Comment: That works quite well for me. Try to play with this functions

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (self.user.exists) {
        return 3;
    }
    return 2;
}
```